# Threejs blank canvas if I use mine

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I am currently trying to display a globe using three-globe. Everything is working fine until I try to use my own canvas. It seems that when I use my own canvas and that the canvas is before my javascript file in the html tree, it does not display it correctly and I have a blank canvas.
here is the code that initialize the canvas :

```
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, canvas: myCanvas });
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    console.log(renderer.domElement)

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
    camera.aspect = width/height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xbbbbbb));
    scene.add(new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.6));

    camera.position.z = 300;
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = 0;

    scene.add(camera);

    scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0x545ef3, 400, 2000);

    // Add camera controls
    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.minDistance = 101;
    controls.rotateSpeed = 1;
    controls.zoomSpeed = 0.3;

    window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);
    window.addEventListener('click', onClick, false); 
    //document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

If I comment the last line, the canvas is present in the tree but it is blank. If i uncomment it appears at the end of the body and it is a black canvas (what is expected here).
Can someone know why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

There are in general three ways you can create a renderer in context of canvas.

1. Without the `canvas` parameter which means the renderer is going to create an internal canvas. It is accessible with `WebGLRenderer.domElement` and needs to be assigned to the DOM, usually via `document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);`.
2. You could already have a canvas in your DOM and query it in JS via e.g. `document.getElementById( 'myCanvas' );`. In this case, you have to apply it to the ctor like in your sample code.
3. The third option is you are creating a canvas inline via e.g. `createElementNS( 'canvas' )`. In this case, you have to apply it when creating the renderer but also append it to the DOM.

According to your description, you are using option 2. In this case, the line `document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);` is not necessary since the canvas is alreay part of the DOM.

I suggest you execute your code when your DOM is ready. Add an event listener to the `DOMContentLoaded` event and execute your `three.js` code there.